# Add Image to UIImageView with its tag

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a multiple Imageview with tags 1,2,3,4...

Now i want to load Images on that Imageviews with their respective tags.

For Eg: If 6 Imageviews are there then,

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
  imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xpos+10,20, 75, 45)];
  xpos+=100;
  imgView.tag=i;

   if ([[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Image"]) //Image is cached then assign it
    {
        imgView.image=[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Image"];
    }
    else //Image is not there download it..
    {
        if ([[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Image"] length]!=0)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                [self downloadImage_3:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Merchant_SmallImage"] AtIndex:i];
            });
        }

    }

}


//Downloads Images asynchronously..
-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSString*)ImageUrl AtIndex:(int)i{

    if ([ImageUrl length]!=0)
    {
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageUrl]]];
        NSLog(@"img = %@",img);
        imgView.image=img;
    }

}
```

After writing this, image is getting downloaded(Log shows some encoded values of `img`) but it is not getting apply on its respective imageview.

**Please help and Thanks in advance.**

Comment: are u adding your imageview as a subview of a view?

Comment: use image lazy loading to load images from url

Answer (score 1):

try the below

```
 //change your download method like
-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSString*)ImageUrl forImageView :(UIImageView *)imgView
{
    if ([ImageUrl length]!=0)
    {
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageUrl]]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [imgView setImage:img];
        });
    }
}

//call your download method like below

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            [self downloadImage_3:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Merchant_SmallImage"] forImageView:imgView]; //pass your ImageView here
        });
```

Comment: i wrote `-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSString*) ImageUrl forImageView :(UIImageView *)imgVw{

    NSLog(@"ImageUrl =%@", ImageUrl);
    if ([ImageUrl length]!=0)
    {
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Path]]];
        
        if (img) {
            [dicImages_msg setObject:img forKey:Path];
        }
        
        imgView.image=[dicImages_msg valueForKey:Path];
    }
    
}` ImageUrl shows path of Url but still image is not getting applied

Comment: what is `Path`?? you used `[Path length]`.

Comment: why you wrote this `imgView.image=[dicImages_msg valueForKey:Path]` ??

Comment: Awesome dude its working when i write `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [imgView setImage:img];
        });`  but the ordering of image is not proper sometimes 2nd image is getting applied to 4th Imageview or 3rd Img is getting applied to 2nd Imageview. :(

Comment: Then check from where you passing your `imageView` i mean `[self downloadImage_3:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Merchant_SmallImage"] forImageView:imgView];`

Comment: I wrote `for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                        [self downloadImage_3:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Merchant_SmallImage"] forImageView:imgView Tag:imgView.tag]; //pass your ImageView here
                    });

}` then

Comment: `-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSString*)Path forImageView :(UIImageView *)imgVw Tag :(int)TagValue{

    if ([Path length]!=0)
    {
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Path]]];
        
        if (img) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [imgVw setImage:img];
            });
        }
    }
    
}`

Answer (score 0):

Where you are adding the allocated image view to the parent view, it is supposed to be done inside the for loop only, every time to assign one image to the image-view you need to add this image-view to the parent view to get it displayed,please check that.

Comment: If i do that way, it takes lots of time for downloading image and i dont want to perform downloading on main thread.